# View in Android taking the whole screen- how to tell the canvas to respect the limits of the view?

Tags: java, android, animation, ondraw, custom-view

EDIT:

OK, so I've extended the lenght and the width of the view to a big part of the screen I can assume that the onDraw() method is NOT TAKING the limits of the view, because it goes through all the screen as I can suppose. So the question now would be **how to tell the canvas to respect the limits of the view?** Any ideas, maybe forcing some parameters?

END OF EDIT

I have implemented some code for drawing a custom view, but the canvas is blank.  I am sure it is running, because I have added log traces, and those are showing up just fine.

**How do I properly implement drawing for custom views, and what is wrong with what I've done below?**

My custom view that goes inside a layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent">

<pis.core.JMI_VistaMenuIn android:layout_height="150dip" android:layout_width="150dip" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:id="@+id/viewAnd01" ></pis.core.JMI_VistaMenuIn>

<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/btnJugar" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Jugar" android:layout_below="@+id/viewAnd01" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/viewAnd01" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/viewAnd01"></Button>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The customview is the one called: pis.core.JMI_VistaMenuIn. In the preview I got an "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException" but when the .apk is loaded the xml layout WORKS.

Here is the code for my custom view.  As I said before, the lines that contain the logging are getting hit, but my canvas is blank:

```
public class JMI_VistaMenuIn extends View {

public static final String QUOTE = "Mind Logic+";

public Animation anim;

//Default constructors

public void createAnim(Canvas canvas) {
    Log.i("SC", "Exe canvas 01");
    anim = new RotateAnimation(0, 360, canvas.getWidth() / 2, canvas
            .getHeight() / 2);
    anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    anim.setDuration(10000L);
    anim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());

    startAnimation(anim);
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    // creates the animation the first time
    if (anim == null) {
        createAnim(canvas);
    }

    Path circle = new Path();

    int centerX = canvas.getWidth() / 2;
    int centerY = canvas.getHeight() / 2;
    int r = Math.min(centerX, centerY);

    circle.addCircle(centerX, centerY, r, Direction.CW);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    paint.setTextSize(30);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);

    canvas.drawTextOnPath(QUOTE, circle, 0, 30, paint);
    Log.i("SC", "Exe canvas 02");
}
}
```

Comment: @Joel: I tried to edit your question to make it more obvious what you're asking.  People tend to be attracted to questions that they already know how to solve, and I'm sure people have tackled this problem before :)  Feel free to roll it back or further improve it if you don't like my changes.

Comment: A few suggestions: try to do something less funky in the `onDraw()` method (just draw a circle or a line), try to clear the canvas before you use it, try to add logging (in particular to check the values of `centerX` and `centerY`)

Comment: @Guillaume Brunerie: Well, that did quite partially worked, I draw one but it just show a little part of a complete circle and it goes through all the screen. This is really driving me nuts!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Similar code works just fine for me, including the animation. You have another issue somewhere else in your code: try setting the paint style.

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    paint.setTextSize(30);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
```

Comment: I've added that LOC but I still face the same issue, and I just don't know where else to look, I've been watching the same lines for a lot of time. Maybe the manifest has something to do with all of this?

Comment: Have you tried this on multiple devices? Perhaps a different emulator or an actual device? I tested it on a Nexus 1 and it works fine.

Comment: I've just tried on 3 different emulators, nothing. Maybe you can share your code with the community? This it's quite troublesome, I've seen a hand of posts regarding this topic with no solution at all.