# Circle in canvas taking entire parent space

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas

My parent view is a RelativeLayout, I added a triangle to it extending the View class. I draw the triangle using canvas and paint. The problem i am facing is that, when i touch on the relative layout, both touch listeners , the relative layout and triangle are being triggered. I just want the triangle to take the exact space as it requires. How can i limit my customview , triangle in this case to take it's space, rather than occupying the entire parent layout.

Actually my requirement is: i have one relative layout on the layout i am adding some custom views dynamically. those have touch listeners for for dragging points in the triangle,but those are taking full screen of my parent view, because of that i am unable to trigger touch listeners separately for parent and child view's.

I've spent countless hours developing solutions for this problem and I just couldn't get my head around it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post your code snippet. Its not possible to provide answers this way.

Comment: Let check with this post---

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686291/view-in-android-taking-the-whole-screen-how-to-tell-the-canvas-to-respect-the-l

Comment: This looks also related to your query; hope it would be helpful to you--- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10229121/how-to-set-canvas-size?rq=1

Comment: @AndroSelva updated my question with some code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I am gathering you are saying,you have a triangle drawn within a `RelativeLayout` in a `CustomView`. The actual `View` size is `FILL_PARENT` for both width and height. So the square representing the **touchable area** of the triangle is the same as the square representing the **touchable area** of the parent `RelativeLayout`.

You would like touch events inside the triangle's drawn area to be received by the triangle `View` and anything outside to be received by the parent. It is not possible to define a custom touch area from what I understand.

That doesn't stop you manipulating drawing bounds and touch focus to accomplish what you want though.

**How it can be done**

1. Ensure that your `CustomView` with the triange **always** receives the touch event. When it receives the touch event, it perform basic maths to figure out if the touch was within your triangle area (you must have your triangle bounds you use to draw your triangle saved as global variables for the `CustomView`).
2. Then a simple conditional statement to determine whether to act on and consume or pass the event on (do you even want a `TouchEvent` on your `RelativeLayout` to do anything? If not that makes this a lot easier).

Example code skeleton:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    boolean inTriangle = false;
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    // This really depends on what behaviour you want, if a drag extends outside the
    // triangle bounds, do you want this to end the touch event? This code could be done
    // more efficiently depending on your choices / needs

    // Do maths to figure out if the point is actually inside the triangle. Once again,
    // many solutions and some much easier than others depending on type of triangle

    // This flow will only register events in the triangle, and do nothing when outside
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        if (inTriangle) {
            // Do whatever it is you want to do

            return true; // to say you consumed the event if necessary
        } else {
            return false; // parent RelativeLayout should now get touch event

    }
} else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
    if (inTriangle) {
        // Do whatever it is you want

        return true;
    } else {
        // Do nothing
        return true; // So is stil consumed
    }
}

return true;
```

}

To be honest, the question is way to open-ended / unclear to give anything more specific. But this is how you would accomplish what you asked. Just apply it to your specific scenario.

**Note:** I have encountered issues with `TouchEvent` passing, so if you really do want to pass them to specific places, you may have to investigate toying with [View.dispatchTouchEvent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#dispatchTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) if the order your Touches are being processed becomes an issue.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Actually my requirement is: i have one relative layout on the layout i am adding some custom views dynamically. those have touch listeners for for dragging points in the triangle,but those are taking full screen of my parent view, because of that i am unable to trigger touch listeners separately for parent and child view's.still you are not clear about this let me know.

Comment: That kinda of information should really be in the question ;) The same sort of stuff does apply though, you will just have to be very controlling with the order your `TouchEvent` is dispatched to the views. Or even, use your RelativeLayout as a "controlling view" and make all the others not accept `TouchEvents` but simply store their bounds as readable member variables. Then just do the maths and appropriate drag actions in the RelativeLayout's onTouchEvent controller. Much simpler and cleaner, especially if your dynamically having many views.

Comment: i was updated my Question, because of this problem i am unable to know which view user was selected for changing background color or some extra features.

Comment: I am still not entirely understanding the exact question. Please post code, or a nice clear screenshot of what you want to accomplish and I'd be more than happy to help. Based on my current understanding of what you want (which I have a feeling could be wrong), I would debate whether you even need the custom views

Comment: aka. If you just want a view where there is a triangle drawn and you drag the corners to resize the triangle, it can be accomplished MUCH easier. I am just not sure exactly what you want still.

Comment: look at this image https://dl.dropbox.com/u/38493970/Custom_view.png i'm creating this custom view by using this code.http://pastebin.com/X3XyxevX. my requirement is i want to implement long press on the custom view for selecting that view. but when i click on relative layout, custom view touch listeners also triggering. if i have more custom view's on relative layout i want select particular view when i want delete it. i think it's happen because of those custom view taking full width and full height of parent view. if it controls to take upto wrapcontent width and height this prb will solve.

Answer (score 1):

You have an issue to handle the touch events of the triangle because you are getting touch on both the view RalativeLayout and Your customview.

To solve this issue you have to do some changes in the customview's onTouchEvent.
Like If you are touching on the customview and if you want to handle the event then from onTouchEvent you will have to return **true** instead of false so that your parent view will not get the touch events.